# How to change the clickable element on onclick-Events after the page was loaded?

Tags: javascript, onclick

When the pages loads, there is one element, which should run a function, when it gets clicked:

```
var myArray = document.querySelectorAll(".my-element");

myArray[(myArray.length)-1].onclick = function() {  
    // function content
}
```

Later on, some of the elements will be replaced, deleted or some new ones will be added.
So *myArray[(myArray.length)-1]* will be another element than before.

And at the moment, this doesn't work. The new element will not listen to my clicking events. Is there any way, to "update" this onclick event?

---

As asked for, here is a simplified version of the html, it is in:

```
<div id="track-1">

<div class="coach">

<div class="my-element">
</div>

<div class="my-element">
</div>

</div>

(... some more coaches, the amount varies ...)


<div class="coach">

<div class="my-element">
</div>

<div class="my-element">
</div>

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use event delegation instead, and use `getElementsByClassName`, which returns a **live** HTMLCollection. On click, check to see if the target is the last element in the collection:

```
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("my-element");
document.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (elements[elements.length - 1].contains(target)) {
    console.log('last element clicked');
  }
});
```

```js
setInterval(() => { document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div class="my-element">click</div>') }, 2000);


const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("my-element");
document.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (elements[elements.length - 1].contains(target)) {
    console.log('last element clicked');
  }
});
```

An more elegant solution could probably be identified given the HTML.

Comment: Thank you very much, works perfect :)

I've added a simplified version of the HTML in my startpost.